# Android application crashes upon opening

Tags: android, crash, logcat

I'm developing an android application and as soon as the AVD opens and I unlock the device and click the menu, I get an "Application stops unexpectedly" error. The following is my logcat log.

```
02-22 11:34:38.220: D/AndroidRuntime(336): Shutting down VM
02-22 11:34:38.220: W/dalvikvm(336): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
02-22 11:34:38.290: E/AndroidRuntime(336): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-22 11:34:38.290: E/AndroidRuntime(336): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.compliment.ComplimentGenerator: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.compliment.ComplimentGenerator
02-22 11:34:38.290: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:466)
02-22 11:34:38.290: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3260)
02-22 11:34:38.290: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-22 11:34:38.290: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:969)
02-22 11:34:38.290: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-22 11:34:38.290: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-22 11:34:38.290: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-22 11:34:38.290: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-22 11:34:38.290: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-22 11:34:38.290: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-22 11:34:38.290: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-22 11:34:38.290: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-22 11:34:38.290: E/AndroidRuntime(336): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.compliment.ComplimentGenerator
02-22 11:34:38.290: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:957)
02-22 11:34:38.290: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:942)
02-22 11:34:38.290: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:461)
02-22 11:34:38.290: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  ... 11 more
```

EDIT: code available here: http://pastebin.com/VSvWvgGa

EDIT2: XML available here: http://pastebin.com/uGLpyUcW

EDIT3: After making the initial changes Druv recommended, I'm getting new logcat errors and I've updated my post with those errors

EDIT4: R.layout.main.xml: http://pastebin.com/Qe8Bx47m

Comment: `java.lang.ClassCastException` Check your code.

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.compliment.ComplimentGenerator, it seems you are trying wrong casting. Without code hard to findout what is going on.

Comment: You are casting something inappropriately in your `ComplimentGenerator` class. Can you post any relevant parts of that class?

Comment: Edited my original post to feature the code

Comment: Please post also your AndroidManifest file.

Comment: Is your Activity correctly defined inside the AndroidManifest.xml file (with correct package name)?

Comment: I've edited my original post to include my Android Manifest XML File

Comment: You have Instrumentation.java ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    AndroidManifest.xml 
    <application android:name="ComplimentGenerator" android:icon="@drawable/icon">

 Just Rename Your
      android:name="ComplimentGenerator"  to   android:label="ComplimentGenerator"
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you add com.compliment over here:

```
<activity android:name="com.compliment.ComplimentGenerator" android:label="ComplimentGenerator">
```

**Edit:**
Change `<activity android:name="ComplimentGenerator" android:label="ComplimentGenerator">` to `<activity android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="ComplimentGenerator">`
From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html),

> **public class Application**
>
> Base class for those who need to maintain global application state.
>   You can provide your own implementation **by specifying its name** in your
>   AndroidManifest.xml's  tag, which will cause that **class
>   to be instantiated for you** when the process for your
>   application/package is created.
>
> There is normally no need to subclass Application. In most situation,
>   static singletons can provide the same functionality in a more modular
>   way. If your singleton needs a global context (for example to register
>   broadcast receivers), the function to retrieve it can be given a
>   Context which internally uses Context.getApplicationContext() when
>   first constructing the singleton.

In other words, when you added android:name, the ComplimentGenerator class was being instantiated. However, ComplimentGenerator was not subclassing Application (which was required), which resulted in a ClassCastException.

Comment: I've added it and I'm getting new logcat errors, I've updated my original post with those.

Comment: can we see your R.layout.main?

Comment: i can't find any R.id.label in your main file. yet you seem to be using it in your class file. could you check this?

Comment: I renamed label to newLabel both in main.xml and in my class

Comment: also, where are you calling the generateCompliment() method from? could you post everything or is that it?

Comment: That's in the class I pasted earlier

Answer (score 1):

I think the "android:name" attribute value is wrong! Use the following (starting with the "."):

```
<activity android:name=".ComplimentGenerator" android:label="ComplimentGenerator">
```

Thus, Android will know the starting activity is com.compliment.ComplimentGenerator

- "com.compliment" comes from the "package" attribute value
- ".ComplimentGenerator" comes from the "android:name" attribute value